# Render a partial view with its own controller in layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

A part of my master layout has a dropdown menu that contains a link to a modal panel for some user settings. I'm not sure how to do this, but so far I've tried the following:

**UserController.cs**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /UserProfile/

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserProfile(string user)
    {
        ViewBag.UserName = user;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**UserProfile.cshtml**

```
<h4>
    Modal Header
</h4>

<p class="help-block">Dummy text</p>
<hr>
@ViewBag.UserName
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
 ....
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <li class="userlinks">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#usrmodal">View Profile <i class="pull-right fa fa-pencil"></i></a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Index", "Logout")</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@RenderBody()
</body>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="usrmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">User Settings</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @{ Html.Action("UserProfile", "User", new { user = @ViewBag.UserName }); }
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
</html>
```

Whenever I try to run this I get an unhandled exception at the line in my `_Layout.cshtml` where I call my `@{ Html.Action("UserProfile", "User", new { user = @ViewBag.UserName }); }`:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll`

How am I supposed to render views like this? Obviously I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View()` renders with Layout, so you get stack overflow. `return PartialView();` should help you.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult UserProfile(string user)
{
    ViewBag.UserName = user;
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working! Could I be so bold to ask for an explanation as to why my ViewBag.UserName is null? Could I delay the call to UserProfile somehow? Or even better, trigger it when the modal is opened?

Comment: You could deal with it with just a simple ajax call, by removing ChildActionAttribute and using jQuery.get; And ViewBag.UserName could be null because you are using it before assigning value.

Answer (score 0):

try casting ViewBag.UserName to string

```
@Html.Action("UserProfile", "User", new { user = (string)ViewBag.UserName });
```